# Selenium, select based on "onclick" value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

With Selenium, I'm trying to find the following checkbox on webpage.

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="             document.getElementById('lastCheminClicked').value='123';             createInputsBinaireCell(25,'colonne5',1,0789,1,1,0,this.checked, this);">
```

The distinctive part is the '123' value in the "onclick", this is what selenium should look for.

Any way to find it on page? I have tried with xpath with no sucess.

Comment: Why not use a xpath with `contains`, that should do the trick, I tried it in chrome on a test-website and it found the right element. What was wrong with your xpath?`$x("//input[contains(@onclick, \"value='123'\")]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XPath selectors](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) allow using [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function which can be used for partial match on the attribute or text value of the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) element.

The relevant selector would be something like:

```
//input[contains(@onlclick, '123')]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the partial value **123** is distinct within the `onclick` event so to locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='checkbox'][onclick*='123']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox' and contains(@onclick,'123')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You might try finding all input tags, and then iterate through each looking at the onclick attribute. For example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

input_tags = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
found_tag = None
for input_tag in input_tags:
    onclick_attribute = input_tag.get_attribute('onclick')
    if ".value='123'" in onclick_attribute:
        found_tag = input_tag
        break
```

You'll probably need exception handling around the `get_attribute` call.